# Why can't a struct be a member of itself?

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct `foo`. Declaring a member of type `foo*` works:

```
typedef struct foo
{
    struct foo* children[26];
} foo;
```

But if I try to declare a member of type `foo` I get an error:

```
typedef struct foo
{
    struct foo children[26];
} foo;
```

This declaration gives me the error

> definition of 'struct foo' is not complete until the closing '}'

Comment: Each post must have one question **only**. I've removed the second question, but you can make a separate post for it.

Comment: Don't use `is_initializes`, use NULL-pointers. Also, best put children pointers at the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A structure `T` cannot contain itself. How would you know its size? It would be impossible to do so, because the size of `T` would require you to know the size of `T` (because `T` contains another `T`). This turns into an infinite recursion.

You can have a pointer to `T` inside a structure `T` because the size of a pointer is not the same size as the pointed-to object: in this case, you would just store an address of memory where another `T` is stored - all the space you need to do that is basically the space you need to store a memory address where another `T` lives.

Comment: You mean, because all pointers to struct are the same size for any implementation.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes. All pointers to `struct T` are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

The structure *Trie* cannot contain another structure *Trie* in it , it will do a never - ending recursion but it may contain a pointer to another structure *Trie*

So first one is correct

```
typedef struct TRIE
{
    bool is_endpoint;
    bool is_initialized;
    struct TRIE* children[26];
} TRIE;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Object of type T can't contains another non-static object of same type. If it may be possible, how to find size of that object? Size of pointer to object is always constant on current system.
2. Check value of `currentptr` for non-NULL before you can access fields of `currentptr` (like `is_endpoint`).